# Why returning the counter takes much time in the following example?

Tags: performance-tuning, compile

Consider the following data and analytic expressions:

```
Exp1[x_, y_, z_] = Sin[x]*Cos[y]*Exp[-z^2];
Exp2[exp1_, x_, y_, z_, t_] = Exp[-exp1^2]*(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)/(x^2+y^2+t^2 + z^2);
Data1 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10^6, 2}];
Data2 = RandomReal[{3, 4}, {100, 2}];
```

as well as two codes doing some routine with these datasets and `Exp1`, `Exp2`:

```
CodeComp3 = 
 Hold@Compile[{{Data1, _Real, 1}, {Data2, _Real, 2}}, 
      Module[{xvals, yvals, zval, tval, count, expr1, expr2},
       count = 0.;
       xvals = Compile`GetElement[Data1, 1];
       yvals = Compile`GetElement[Data1, 2];
       Do[
        zval = Compile`GetElement[Data2, j, 1];
        tval = Compile`GetElement[Data2, j, 2];
        expr1 = Exp1[xvals, yvals, zval];
        expr2 = Exp2[expr1, xvals, yvals, zval, tval];
        count+=1., {j, 1, Length[Data2], 1}];
       {count}
       ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True] /. 
    DownValues@Exp1 /. DownValues@Exp2 // ReleaseHold

CodeComp31 = 
 Hold@Compile[{{Data1, _Real, 1}, {Data2, _Real, 2}}, 
      Module[{xvals, yvals, zval, tval, count, expr1, expr2},
       count = 0.;
       xvals = Compile`GetElement[Data1, 1];
       yvals = Compile`GetElement[Data1, 2];
       Do[
        zval = Compile`GetElement[Data2, j, 1];
        tval = Compile`GetElement[Data2, j, 2];
        expr1 = Exp1[xvals, yvals, zval];
        expr2 = Exp2[expr1, xvals, yvals, zval, tval];
        count += expr1*expr2, {j, 1, Length[Data2], 1}];
       {count}
       ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True] /. 
    DownValues@Exp1 /. DownValues@Exp2 // ReleaseHold
```

Inside `Do`, they do exactly the same thing. The only difference is what the code returns. `CodeComp31` returns `count` summed as `expr1*expr2`, while `CodeComp3` returns `count` summed as `+=1`.

However, `CodeComp31` evaluates for a much longer time:

```
CodeComp3[Data1, Data2]; // AbsoluteTiming
CodeComp31[Data1, Data2]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0434682, Null}
>
> {0.174595, Null}

Moreover, if changing `count+=1` in `CodeComp3` to `count+=expr1`, the required time grows to 0.1.

Could you please tell me what may cause this difference? Am I right that `CodeComp3` evaluates nothing except for the code required to compute the sum `count`? I.e., using `+=1` only evaluates `count+=1` and does not call the remaining routine. While using `+=expr1` evaluates `expr1` but does not evaluate `expr2`.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon after `count += expr1*expr2` in `CodeComp3`.

Comment: @Roman : sorry, you are totally correct, that row was a mistake, I have removed it.

Comment: I guess the C compiler figures out that `expr1` and `expr2` are nowhere used and just removes their computation from `CodeComp3`. (It must be the C compiler, because `ExportString[CodeComp3, "C"]` and `ExportString[CodeComp31, "C"]` return nearly identical code.) A decent compiler could also figure out the result of `count` and delete the entire loop along with all other memory fetches.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher : Thanks! How do you think, is it true that `CodeComp31` cannot be made faster without some heavy work?